# Get object from sub list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data structure. Object A contains a list of B. B contains a list of C.

```
A
{
   int id;
   List<B>;
}

B
{
   int id;
   List<C>;
}

C
{
   int id;
}
```

I have the object A, and I have the B.id, and C.id that I want to find. I have LINQ to do this:

```
A = SomeMethodToGetA();
int bid = 2;
int cid = 20;
B foundB = A.B.Where(item => item.id = bid).First()
C foundC = B.C Where(item => item.id = cid).First()
```

I was wondering if there was a way to perform the above statements into a single LINQ statement.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just chain two `Single` queries:

```
C foundC = A.B.Single(item => item.id == bid)
            .C.Single(item => item.id == cid)
```

This will throw an exception if there is not a matching `B` or a matching `C` within that `B`, but your original queries will also.  If those are issues then your original query (adding null-checking) may be more straight-forward.

Comment: I'd also add that Single and First are semantically different, although the latter is usually abused.

Comment: Also note that `.Single` expects *exactly one* element in the list to match the condition and throws an exception otherwise (0 matches or more than one), while `.First` expects *at least one* element to match (and returns the first one that does).

Comment: Thanks for the reply D Stanley. I will use A.B.SingleOrDefault(item => item.id == bid). How would you handle the case where this statement returns null, and assign foundC as null

Comment: If the intermediate value could be null then it will be cleaner to use two queries, checking the intermediate result for `null`.